# Android upload image php server use AsynTask

Tags: php, android, asynchronous, server

Hie, guys. 
I have tried to upload a file to my laptop as a server. why each of my error like this =

```
 <br/> <Parse error> </ br> syntax error, unexpected T_Variable in <b> /imgupload/upload_image.php </ b> on line <b> 6 </ b> <br/>
```

this is my android code...

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    String encodedString;
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    String imgPath, fileName;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Set Cancelable as False
        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }

    // When Image is selected from Gallery
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                // Set the Image in ImageView
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgPath));
                // Get the Image's file name
                String fileNameSegments[] = imgPath.split("/");
                fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
                // Put file name in Async Http Post Param which will used in Php web app
                params.put("filename", fileName);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }

    // When Upload button is clicked
    public void uploadImage(View v) {
        // When Image is selected from Gallery
        if (imgPath != null && !imgPath.isEmpty()) {
            prgDialog.setMessage("Converting Image to Binary Data");
            prgDialog.show();
            // Convert image to String using Base64
            encodeImagetoString();
        // When Image is not selected from Gallery
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "You must select image from gallery before you try to upload",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    // AsyncTask - To convert Image to String
    public void encodeImagetoString() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            protected void onPreExecute() {

            };

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
                options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 3;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath,
                        options);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
                byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
                // Encode Image to String
                encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                prgDialog.setMessage("Calling Upload");
                // Put converted Image string into Async Http Post param
                params.put("image", encodedString);
                // Trigger Image upload
                triggerImageUpload();
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    public void triggerImageUpload() {
        makeHTTPCall();
    }

    // Make Http call to upload Image to Php server
    public void makeHTTPCall() {
        prgDialog.setMessage("Invoking Php");      
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        // Don't forget to change the IP address to your LAN address. Port no as well.
        client.post("http://192.168.2.43/imgupload/upload_image.php",
                params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    // When the response returned by REST has Http
                    // response code '200'
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {
                        // Hide Progress Dialog
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    // When the response returned by REST has Http
                    // response code other than '200' such as '404',
                    // '500' or '403' etc
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                            String content) {
                        // Hide Progress Dialog
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        // When Http response code is '404'
                        if (statusCode == 404) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Requested resource not found",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        // When Http response code is '500'
                        else if (statusCode == 500) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Something went wrong at server end",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        // When Http response code other than 404, 500
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error Occured n Most Common Error: n1. Device not connected to Internetn2. Web App is not deployed in App servern3. App server is not runningn HTTP Status code : "
                                            + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        // Dismiss the progress bar when application is closed
        if (prgDialog != null) {
            prgDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my php code (/img/upload_image.php)...

```
<?php
    // Get image string posted from Android App
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    // Get file name posted from Android App
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
    // Decode Image
    $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    // Images will be saved under 'www/imgupload/uplodedimages' folder
    $file = fopen('uploadedimages/'.$filename, 'wb');
    // Create File
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';
?>
```

i was add in manifest, permission internet and write external storage

thank's before...

Comment: Can you please post the file `/imgupload/upload_image.php` ? There seems to be a syntax error around line 6, which is independent of the Java code. The PHP code you posted here, has a valid syntax.

Comment: thank's @DanielMarschall.. my coding php is...which is above ^^

Comment: Please use a service like pastebin to post code in comments. Your code in this comment is exactly the code you wrote in your question. I did read your question. But this code has no syntax error. But according to the error message, there must be an syntax error in /imgupload/upload_image.php at line 6. In your code, line 6 is a comment. That's doesn't make sense. Please show us your *real* code of the file /imgupload/upload_image.php .

Comment: Ok @DanielMarschall..

this is my file..
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1qf73381155rff/upload_image.php?dl=0

Comment: Why convert the image to a base64 representation and not just send it as a file using a multipart mime type?  Have you verified that both the "image" and "filename" variables are set when uploading?

Comment: @Chris : Thank's chris.. can you give me example coding multipart mime type ? I have tried a lot of source code to upload image php server but all failed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you might do it using a multipart request.  Be sure to wrap the method call in a background thread or you'll get an exception about running it on the main thread.

```
public String multipartRequest(final String urlTo, final String post, final String filepath, final String filefield) throws ParseException, IOException {

    String result = "";
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";

    result = "";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    String[] q = filepath.split("/");
    int idx = q.length - 1;

    try {
        File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), filepath);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        URL url = new URL(urlTo);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + filefield + "\"; filename=\"" + q[idx] +"\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/png" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while(bytesRead > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        // Upload POST Data
        String[] posts = post.split("&");
        int max = posts.length;

        for(int i=0; i<max;i++) {
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            int positionOfEqual = posts[i].indexOf("=");
            if (posts[i].length() == (positionOfEqual + 1)) posts[i] = posts[i] + "_";

            String kv[] = posts[i].split("=");

            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + kv[0] + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain"+lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(kv[1]);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        result = convertStreamToString(inputStream);

        fileInputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();


    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("MultipartRequest", "Multipart Form Upload Error");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return result;


}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: hie thank's your source code.. i was try it,  why (getActivity) error in my project... and I dont understand...
How to  get  (", final String filepath, final String filefield") , in my image from gallery. can you help me ?

Comment: Sorry - I had written this for a Fragment.  If you're using it in an Activity, remove the getActivity() reference.  So, that line would be:
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), filepath);

Comment: For filepath, enter in the name of an image in your cache directory.  For "filefield", enter the field name your php script is expecting.